# Loop that stops when condition is met, that sets state depending on window scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I managed to get an array of refs of sections on my page that looks like this:

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {current: div.single-section}
1: {current: div.single-section}
2: {current: div.single-section}
3: {current: div.single-section}
4: {current: div.single-section}
5: {current: div.single-section}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I passed it from Sections component to CategoryNav component, where in Navbar I have categories that are corresponding to those sections. Every single-section has data-id that is equal to category id. Now, my goal is to, depending on what section is on screen give the corresponding category in navbar class "active". That all I did and it works. The problem which I have is this function on eventListener scroll that sets my state to data-id of single section which will give corresponding category with this id class "active" and that all I have done. The only problem I have is this function:

```
const activeCategory = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
      if (
        window.pageYOffset > myArr[i].current.offsetTop &&
        myArr[i].current.offsetTop < myArr[i].current.offsetTop + myArr[i].current.getBoundingClientRect().height
      );
      {
        setCurrentCategory(myArr[i].current.dataset.id);
        break;
      }
    }
  };
```

I want to loop this array, and check if first section's is basically on the screen, if it is, it sets my state to dataset.id of this section, if it is not, it goes to next item. I wrote this, but it stays on first item, no mather what is on the screen, it just doesn't go to next item. Can anyone help?

Comment: You have a `;` after the `if` condition

Comment: Still doesn't work @VLAZ

Comment: Then we need to know how that condition evaluates. But we cannot do it without a [mcve]. The easiest thing would be for you to debug it or at least add some logging and see how the code behaves, then isolate what doesn't work.

Comment: `...offsetTop < ...offsetTop + ...getBoundingClientRect().height` is equivalent to `...getBoundingClientRect().height > 0`. 
I think you meant `window.pageYOffset < myArr[i].current.offsetTop + myArr[i].current.getBoundingClientRect().height`.

Comment: *"Loop that stops when condition is met"* What is [Array#find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

While trying on the code below, it also stops at first iteration with `;` right after `if(i == 73)`. As stated by @VLAZ. The same thing happens as the issue you report. Please double check this `;` is not your problem.

```js
/* All prime numbers below 100 */
const limit = 100;
const isPrime = num => {
    for(let i = 2, s = Math.sqrt(num); i <= s; i++)
        if(num % i === 0) return false; 
    return num > 1;
}

for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
  if(isPrime(i)) {
    console.log(i);
    if(i == 73); {
      break; // break loop before given `i < limit` condition
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this instead

```
myArr.forEach(i => {
      if (
        window.pageYOffset > i.current.offsetTop &&
        i.current.offsetTop < i.current.offsetTop + i.current.getBoundingClientRect().height
      ) {
        setCurrentCategory(i.current.dataset.id);
      }
```

and it's working, but thanks for answers :D

Comment: you can replace `i.current.offsetTop < i.current.offsetTop + ` with `0 < ` because you're only testing wether the `height > 0` here